# Zsh completion with fzf-tab doesn't work with dotnet command

Tags: zsh, zsh-completion, fzf

I enabled zsh completion and added fzf-tab via zinit. It works as expected. I added some custom/extra completions e.g., aws cli and it also worked as expected.

However, when I tried to enable the completion for dotnet as recommended it didn't work with fzf. Please see the screenshots below and the code from my .zshrc for the completions.

What am I missing to get dotnet cli work with fzf-tab completion menu?

```
[![autoload bashcompinit; bashcompinit
autoload -Uz compinit; compinit

_comp_options+=(globdots) # With hidden files
_dotnet_zsh_complete()
{

local completions=("$(dotnet complete "$words")")
reply=( "${(ps:\n:)completions}" )

}

compctl -K _dotnet_zsh_complete dotnet
complete -C "/usr/local/bin/aws_completer" aws][1]][1]
```

This is how it looks with system commands e.g., cp when I press TAB
[image]

This is how it looks with AWS CLI when I press TAB
[image: AWS completion]

This is how it looks with dotnet CLI when I press TAB
[image]